Непонятная причина ошибки "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute"
У меня есть механизм типа pub/sub, реализованный через Queue<T>, где я в delegate помещаю сообщение в очередь, а затем в общем цикле начинаю их обработку используя Dataflow.ActionBlock для того чтобы ограничить максимальное количество блоков через MaxDegreeOfParallelism:
Console.WriteLine($"Processing {ClosedOrders.Count} closed orders ...");
var closedOrdersBlock = new ActionBlock<OrderMessage>(OnPositionClosed,
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 });
while (ClosedOrders.Count > 0)
{
   ClosedOrders.TryDequeue(out var closedOrder);
   if (closedOrder != null)
      closedOrdersBlock.Post(closedOrder);
 }

 closedOrdersBlock.Complete();
 closedOrdersBlock.Completion.Wait();

Вот обработка delegate:
protected virtual void OnPositionClose(OrderMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var orderToClose in ClosedOrders.ToList())
            {
                if (message.Order == null || orderToClose.Order == null ||
                    orderToClose.Order.Ticket != message.Order.Ticket) continue;
                Console.WriteLine("Duplicate order for closing received for ticket " + orderToClose.Order.Ticket +
                                  ", skipping");
                return;
            }

            ClosedOrders.Enqueue(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to enqueue order with ticket {message.Order?.Ticket} for closing: {ex.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Stack trace: {ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }

Возникает ошибка

"Failed to enqueue order for closing: Collection was modified;
enumeration operation may not execute."

, которая как я понимаю возникает из-за того что я добавляю в очередь новые записи в то время пока ведется обработка очереди, хотя исключение говорит что это случается в самом делегате в цикле foreach. Что это означает? В нём я не меняю, а просто прохожусь по списку и проверяю данные, но никак его не изменяю.
Или это связано с тем что пока ведется обработка новая запись помещается в очередь?

"Failed to enqueue order for closing" - это ваш текст ошибки? Такого текста нет приведённом коде. Хотя, если вы вырезали кусок текста, то это оно. В целом да, если OnPositionClose может выполняться параллельно в нескольких потоках одновременно, то и операция ClosedOrders.Enqueue(message); может выполняться в нескольких потоках одновременно. Какая при этом будет ошибка я не знаю, возможно именно та, которую вы наблюдаете. Навскидку можно попробовать использовать вместо Queue -> ConcurrentQueue.

А возможно, ошибка таки на .ToList() происходит, если коллекция у него внутри успела поменяться и там на это проверка сделана. Именно для этого нужно показывать стек-трейс в вопросе - чтобы было видно, где исключение произошло. Лечение тоже самое - перейти на потокобезопасную коллекцию.

@CrazyElf потокобезопасная коллекция - это ConcurrentQueue? Я использовал ToList у очереди как раз для этого - чтобы скопировать и итерировать по списку вместо очереди, но почему-то это не работает.

Ну, потому что при многопоточности коллекция может измениться не только до или после .ToList(), но и прямо во время его выполнения. И .NET следит за такими вещами. Видимо, прямо в момент создания энумератора коллекция поменялась.

Так а какая разница что очередь меняется, когда на его основе создался список, через который и происходит итерация? Список же не меняется ...

Возможно я и не прав в чём-то. Но. Операция .ToList() не атомарна, её тоже какой-то код внутри самого .NET делает и именно этот код вам говорит что-то типа "я тут сделал энумератор по коллекции, но пока я его делал, коллекция успела поменяться, я не понимаю, что с этим делать". Потому что теперь в списке будут не все элементы коллекции, которые в ней есть на данный момент. А является ли это лично для вас проблемой, .NET не знает и кидает исключение - разбирайтесь, мол, сами. У ConcurrentQueue такой проблемы вроде бы не должно быть, она потокобезопасная.

Странное какое-то закрытие вопроса. При чём здесь опечатки??

@CrazyElf Видимо не было кода, через который можно было воспроизвести проблему ...

.ToList() когда делает снапшот коллекции, так же её итерирует как и foreach. То есть исключение возникает не в цикле, а внутри ToList.
Используйте потокобезопасные коллекции или примитивы синхронизации.

Ещё посоветую делать TaArray вместо ToList, если полученную коллекцию не требуется изменять. Работа с массивами имеет выше производительность, чем со списками.
